# NGINX server works normally in LAN, but doesn't work outside of it

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am running a Django project on NGINX + UWSGI. It's working properly in LAN, but from outside it shows just the NGINX default page. What can be a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your router is redirecting the traffic to your nginx server, also check if your ISP is giving you an public IP, there is several scenarios that won't let you access to you nginx server please check if the you have a public IP and then we you can check your router in order to check if the http traffic is being redirected to your local server

Comment: There's not any problem in redirecting, I can access server, but it shows me default page instead of my Django project.

Comment: so you need config your nginx to make a proxy pass I am not sure which config are you using but you can follow this tutorial to review your current config and make some changes

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04